# Is it possible to run grunt in project that use gulp?

Tags: gulp, gruntjs

Currently I'm working in project that using gulp, but for some reason in my machine is little bit slow, so the question is can I use grunt in project that use gulp?

Comment: yes, you can replace gulp tasks with grunt tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
can I use grunt in project that use gulp?
```

Of course you can, but you will duplicate all the preprocessing modules(one for `gulp` and one for `grunt`) and the build configuration/logic hence adding additional complexity. Yuck.

```
but for some reason in my machine is little bit slow
```

`gulp` is faster - in theory - since it does it's processing in-memory rather than doing heavy I/O by writing to temp. files which is what `grunt` does. The task runner is - most probably - not the cause of your problems.

`gulp`/`grunt` are just task runners - the modules themselves and the way they are configured are causing the slowdown, not the task runner that runs them.

You are - most likely

- watching/preprocessing files that you don't need to.
- performing production-readiness tasks far too often.

  - You might have a module that compresses all the images which you run every time a file changes. Put those heavy tasks into a task run that is run just just once before you push into production
  - ES6 -> ES5 transpilation? That's usually heavy. Keep this into a just-before-production task as well

Optimise what you have, especially if it's not *your* project.